# Determine if any kind of list, sequence, array, or IEnumerable is empty

Tags: f#, ivalueconverter

I am writing a Xamarin.Forms app using XAML for my views, and I am trying to write an `IValueConverter` whose job should be returning `false` if the input is "empty" for types where those semantics make sense (strings/lists/sequences/arrays/IEnumerables). I have started with the following, which returns false for empty strings, but I can't figure out how to extend this to lists, sequences, arrays, and IEnumerables:

```
type FalseIfEmptyConverter() =
  interface IValueConverter with 
    member __.Convert(value:obj, _, _, _) = 
      match value with
      | :? string as s -> (s <> "" && not (isNull s)) |> box
      // TODO: extend to enumerables
      | x -> invalidOp <| "unsupported type " + x.GetType().FullName

    member __.ConvertBack(_, _, _, _) =
      raise <| System.NotImplementedException()
```

Things I've tried that don't work:

- `:? list<_>` does not match a (boxed) list (at least not of ints) and produces a warning `This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by its type annotations. The type variable implied by the use of a '#', '_' or other type annotation at or near [...] has been constrained to be type 'obj'`
- `:? list<obj>` does not produce the warning, but also doesn't match a boxed list of ints
- It's the same with `:? seq<_>` and `:? seq<obj>`
- It's the same with `:? System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<obj>` and `IEnumerable<_>` (and if I place it below a similar `seq` match as given above, it warns that the rule will never be matched, which makes sense since AFAIK `seq` corresponds to `IEnumerable`)

Comment: `match value with
| :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as s -> s.GetEnumerator().MoveNext() |> not | x -> invalidOp <| "unsupported type " + x.GetType().FullName`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Foggy Finder's idea to use the non-generic `IEnumerable`:

```
let isEmpty (x:obj) =
    match x with
    | null -> true
    | :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as xs -> xs |> Seq.cast |> Seq.isEmpty
    | _ -> invalidOp <| "unsupported type " + x.GetType().FullName

isEmpty "" // true
isEmpty [] // true
isEmpty (set []) // true
isEmpty [||] // true
isEmpty null // true

isEmpty "a" // false
isEmpty [|1|] // false

isEmpty 1 // exception
```

All of the types that you want to test are sub-types of `Seq<'a>`, which is exactly the same as `IEnumerable<'a>` (including `string`, which is a `seq<char>`). But this is also sub-type of a non-generic type called `IEnumerable` (note the lack of type parameter). This is similar to an `IEnumerable<obj>`, where every item has been boxed. This is why we can cast all of these to `IEnumerable`, then use `Seq.cast` to convert that into `IEnumerable<obj>` so that we can use `Seq.empty`, which only works on the generic type.

Comment: Works wonderfully, thanks! But I don't really understand why must use `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<obj>`. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: When doing a type test, a `string` is a `seq<char>`, and a `char` is an `obj`, but a `string` is not a `seq<obj>`. The check for ancestor types does not extend down to the type parameters, even though it could in theory. I don't know why F# behaves that way or if it is actually because of .NET, or if there is a fundamental difficulty here vs just a lack of the feature.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up and is more or less what I suspected.